# Mockito fails when junit3 is on the classpath

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm working on a project that has a lot of legacy junit3 test. We've recently switched to JUnit 5 and are running the old tests through junit-vintage. For several reasons, we were not able to easily get rid of the junit3 dependency, so it's still on the classpath (which doesn't cause any problems so far).

The problems arise when using `mockito.verify()`, in a test that catches a difference in arguments:

```
public class TestTestTest {
    interface Foo {
        void frobnicate(int a);
    }

    @Test
    void testMockito() {
        Foo foo = mock(Foo.class);
        foo.frobnicate(42);
        verify(foo).frobnicate(43);
    }
}
```

results in

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/mockito/internal/junit/ExceptionFactory$JUnitArgsAreDifferent.create(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/AssertionError; @10: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'org/mockito/exceptions/verification/junit/ArgumentsAreDifferent' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'java/lang/AssertionError' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @10
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String' }
    stack: { 'org/mockito/exceptions/verification/junit/ArgumentsAreDifferent' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: bb00 0259 2a2b 2cb7 0003 b0            


    at org.mockito.internal.junit.ExceptionFactory.canLoadJunitClass(ExceptionFactory.java:33)
    at org.mockito.internal.junit.ExceptionFactory.<clinit>(ExceptionFactory.java:12)
    at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.Reporter.argumentsAreDifferent(Reporter.java:313)
    at org.mockito.internal.verification.checkers.MissingInvocationChecker.checkMissingInvocation(MissingInvocationChecker.java:43)
    at org.mockito.internal.verification.Times.verify(Times.java:37)
    at org.mockito.internal.verification.MockAwareVerificationMode.verify(MockAwareVerificationMode.java:27)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerImpl.handle(MockHandlerImpl.java:72)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.NullResultGuardian.handle(NullResultGuardian.java:29)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.InvocationNotifierHandler.handle(InvocationNotifierHandler.java:35)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.doIntercept(MockMethodInterceptor.java:63)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.doIntercept(MockMethodInterceptor.java:49)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor$DispatcherDefaultingToRealMethod.interceptAbstract(MockMethodInterceptor.java:128)
    at test.TestTestTest$Foo$MockitoMock$448839763.setValue(Unknown Source)
    at test.TestTestTest.testMockito(TestTestTest.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:513)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:170)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:166)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:113)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:113)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:121)
```

The underlying reason seems to be a linker error (`ArgumentsAreDifferent` is a junit4 `AssertionError`, but not a junit3 `AssertionError`)

Is there a workaround for this, assuming I cannot get rid of the junit3 dependency?

Comment: Have you tried to add Junit4 to classpath?

Comment: @uli That's already on there (it needs to be for junit-vintage to work).

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error with Mockito. However there was `com.google.android.tools:dx:1.7` instead of JUnit3. But looks like this dependency contains at least some JUnit3's packages and classes.
The problem here is that Mockito creates `ArgumentsAreDifferent` class that extends `junit.framework.ComparisonFailure`. In JUnit 4 `ComparisonFailure` through intermediate classes extends `java.lang.AssertionError` what is expected by Mockito. But in JUnit 3 (and com.google.android.tools:dx) `ComparisonFailure` does not extend `AssertionError`.

I've fixed it with just excluding this dependency as it was actually not needed for me. 
Do not know how to fix this in your case as JUnit3 is required. Maybe classloading order or something. But hope this information will be helpful.